# MySQL Order-By Bug

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, mysql-error-1054

If I run the following query:

```
select * from mysql.user order by abcdef;
```

MySQL throws the following error:

> ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column
>   'abcdef' in 'order clause'

If I run the following similar query:

```
select * from mysql.user order by "abcdef";
```

MySQL now runs the query and disregards the order by clause (since the mysql.user table lacks a column called 'abcdef').

Is this a bug in MySQL? Why would you want the order by to fail silently when the phrase is in quotes? Wouldn't an error message be appropriate when running order by on a non-existent column?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't disregard it, it orders by **the string** "abcdef", not the column. It does exactly what you ask : ordering by some arbitrary string (which most likely does nothing at all).

Most RDBMS doesn't accept to order by a constant (it doesn't make sense), but MySQL does.

Comment: Yes, but what would happen if I actually had a column named "abcdef". Would the order by "abcdef" work then?

Comment: It would do exactly the same thing as it does now because "abcdef" is a string, not a column.  order by abcdef would work though.

Comment: +1 Compare this to the common typo `SELECT 8 FROM Table`, which returns... `8`. All the SQL engines that I've seen will faithfully SELECT and ORDER BY constants - such behavior just doesn't happen to be useful all that often. :)

Comment: Not with MySQL. Some RDBMS (PostgreSQL for instance) assume that strings are enclosed within single-quotes and columns within double-quotes, but for MySQL, both are considered as strings.

Comment: Not the string literal no, but if you specify the column name without the quotes, then yes.

Answer (score 3):

When you are not using quotes, it would assume that you are referring to a column name, *which does not exist*.

**This is correct functionallity**

Answer (score -1):

The order by expects the field you want to order and if you want it ascending you put asc next to it, and if you want it descending you put a desc like as follows

```
SELECT *
  FROM mysq.user
 ORDER BY username ASC
```